# Plot a spiral where r=theta^2 for 0<= theta <= 10*pi ...in python

Tags: python

so my question is how to make a polar plot `r = f(theta)` for a function `f` by calculating `r` for a range of values of theta and then converting `r` and theta to Cartesian coordinates using equations `x = r cos(theta)` , `y = r sin(theta)`.

BUT I need to plot the spiral `r = (theta)^2` for `0 <= theta <= 10*pi`
this is what I have so far....not getting a spiral here.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, pi
from numpy import linspace

for theta in linspace(0,10*pi):
        r = ((theta)**2)
        x = r*cos(theta)
        y = r*sin(theta)


plt.plot(x,y)  
plt.savefig("spiral.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are erasing your variable each iteration. You are just plotting the last couple of point instead of ploting a serie of couple of point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a list of values, not just a single point. In your case, you keep calculating `x` and `y`, but never save them anywhere. So all you are plotting is the pair `(x,y)` after the last iteration.

```
x = []
y = []
for theta in linspace(0,10*pi):
    r = ((theta)**2)
    x.append(r*cos(theta))
    y.append(r*sin(theta))

plt.plot(x,y)  
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: Sprial]

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.radians(np.linspace(0,360*5,1000))
r = theta**2
x_2 = r*np.cos(theta)
y_2 = r*np.sin(theta)
plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
plt.plot(x_2,y_2)
plt.show()
```

[image: spiral.png]